# To retrieve only BCol from DiagramObject.Style

Tags: vbscript, enterprise-architect

I could get the style of my component from my EA by using this:

```
             dim ajay
            ajay = diagramObject.Style
            Session.Output(ajay)
```

and the output that I get is :

```
DUID=01ABDAAA;BCol=16764057;LCol=-1;LWth=1;
```

I would like to have only BCol but not the rest parameter as I don't need kindly help he out in this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
sub main
    dim test 
    test = "DUID=01ABDAAA;BCol=16764057;LCol=-1;LWth=1;"
    dim key
    key = "BCol="
    dim splitted
    splitted = Split(test,";")
    dim keyValue
    for each keyValue in splitted
        if left(keyValue, len(key))= key then
            Session.Output keyValue
            exit for
        end if
    next
end sub

main
```